# How to go on with Vaadin Touchkit and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, vaadin-touchkit

I found the new solution for the Vaadin Touchkit supporting Spring: 
https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/spring-vaadin-touchkit

Now I created a new Touchkit project out of the maven archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-touchkit \
  -DarchetypeVersion=4.0.0 \
  -DgroupId=example.com -DartifactId=myproject \
  -Dversion=0.1.0 \
  -DApplicationName=My -Dpackaging=war
```

What do I have to do to get Spring working in the Touchkit? I also added the official Spring addon from Vaadin. I can't find any tutorial how to go along with Touchkit and Spring. And which annotations can I use?!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" here is that both Vaadin Spring and Vaadin TouchKit needs their custom servlet to work perfectly. (Until Vaadin4Spring or official Vaadin Spring properly supports TouchKit,) I'd suggest to customise the VaadinSpringServlet to contain the TouchKit stuff.

I made [an integration example to github](https://github.com/mstahv/vaadin-spring-touchkit).